# Show that a certain ratio of diagonal entries dominates a certain ratio of singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, positivity

Let $D=[d_{ij}]_{i,j=1,\ldots,4}$ be a $4 \times 4$ “density matrix”, that is, a Hermitian (possibly symmetric) positive definite matrix having trace 1—that is, the (nonnegative) diagonal entries sum to 1. Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be the two diagonal $2 \times 2$ blocks of $D$. Further, $p= \sqrt{d_{11} d_{44}/(d_{22} d_{33})}$ and $q$ equal the ratio of the two singular values of $D_2^{1/2} D_1^{-1/2}$.
Show that $\min (p,1/p) \geq  \min (q,1/q)$.

Comment: As a brute force, one can show that in diagonal case the inequality turns into the equality, and introducing two parameters for $d_{12}$ and $d_{34}$ just analyze the behavior of singular values ratio as a function of two variables. It may be more convenient then to do a similarity transform to $D_1^{-1/2} D_2 D_1^{-1/2}$ and work with $D_1^{-1} D_2$

Comment: I verified the (equality) assertion of VorKir in the diagonal case. Further, "the  behavior of the singular values ratio as a function of two variables" that he requests is $\epsilon=\exp \left(-\cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 d_{12} d_{34} \mu -\mu ^2-1}{2 \sqrt{d_{12}^2-1}
   \sqrt{d_{34}^2-1} \mu }\right)\right)$. I can give some interesting background (shortly to be an arXiv posting) on this result, if requested.

Comment: What is $\mu$ in your formula? In general, it would be interesting to know the background, just out of curiosity. I think there should be a nice and elegant argument working to proof the inequality, but cannot suggest it:)

Comment: My apologies--I mixed some notation. Actually, $\mu \equiv p$. See Lemma 5 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf for what I used to get the formula. In that paper, $\epsilon$ is the ratio of singular values, denoted $q$ in my original question. (I didn't fully understand your earlier point about a similarity transform.)

Comment: OK, let me try to get this right using the notation of the problem I put (rather than the one I had been working with). Now, $q=\exp \left(-\cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{2 d_{12} d_{34} p}{\sqrt{d_{11} d_{22}}
   \sqrt{d_{33} d_{44}}}-p^2-1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{d_{12}^2}{d_{11} d_{22}}-1}
   \sqrt{\frac{d_{34}^2}{d_{33} d_{44}}-1} p}\right)\right)$.

Comment: To add to the interesting observation of VorKir, "the inequality turns into the equality", not only in the diagonal case, but more broadly, if only the (off-diagonal) 12-, 21-, 34- and 43-entries are zero.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/q/262943/37212, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2157393/14578.   Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Please comment on whether this question fits, in your opinion, MO better than MSE. My guess would be that this may even be off-topic at MO.

Comment: Well, it seems that I should better inform myself as to the scope of the different stack exchanges. I can understand the desire for definite boundaries, but many areas are "interdisciplinary". Are the stack exchanges designed to correspond to specific disciplines? I'll definitely be more circumspect about cross-posting in the future--since it seems to annoy folks.